# Erro ao restringir datas no SQL Server

Tags: sql, data, filtro

Eu recebo 3 bases que são montadas em locais diferentes, essas bases vem pra mim em arquivo de texto (.txt) e eu faço a importação para o SQL Server.

Eu estou fazendo uma *query* no qual eu quero restringir os registros só para o ano de 2014 porém mesmo colocando `Data >= '01/01/2014'` ele continua aparecendo registros de 2012 e 2013.

Comment: Não seria o formato da data que você está passando?

Comment: Eu pensei nisto, mas não sei o formato atual, os .txts só chegam pra mim todo dia. Mas é uma possibilidade.

Comment: `Data >= '2014/01/01'` deve retornar o resultado esperado.

Comment: Reduziu de 1200 registros pra 600, sendo que ainda tem de 2013 e 2012 kkkk

Comment: Qual o tipo do campo no BD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testa isso

```
YEAR(Data) IN '2014'
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Lucas!! Funcionou!

Comment: Só arruma a resposta correta pra quem tiver a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Pronto!!!!!!!!!